# Help for install grahpical boot loader in Linux Ubuntu Budgie Desktop 18.04.1

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, burg

I use Ubuntu Linux with Budgie Desktop 18.04.1

It has a very nice and aesthetic interface, my big problem that I have installed Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu Desktop Budgie 18.04.1, but I do not like the text mode boot manager that is the Grub.

I have seen that this boot manager is Burg, which is graphical mode, but I have tried vainly to install it and I can not.

I have visited several pages and all are unanimous in using these commands in a terminal, to install Burg but I get an error in some packages and it always tells me that it could not find the Burg package to install it.

I use these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa: n-muench / burg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes
```

I guess it's for versions prior to Linux 18.04.

Please if someone can guide me how to install Burg on Linux Ubuntu Budgie Desktop 18.04.1 or some other boot graphical manager, showing the icons of the operating systems and giving the possibility with a simple click of the mouse to select.

Comment: `ppa:n-muench/burg` is supposed to be one word, without spaces. Did you run the command with spaces?